# combining dataframes using rbind + adding a separate column that includes the names of the individual dataframes

Tags: r, rbind

Just a question on rbind.

When running  `df_all <- rbind(df_1, df_2 ...)` to combine multiple dataframes, I was wondering whether is it possible to add in a separate column that includes the names of the individual dataframes where each observation originates from?

Many Thanks,
Mervyn

Comment: `dplyr::bind_rows(df_1, df_2, .., .id = 'id')` ?

Comment: Hey Ronak, thanks for your answer! I tried this out, and while it does generate a separate column, it does not contain the names of the dataframe that each observation belongs to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach :

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- bind_rows(lst(df_1, df_2), .id = 'id')
```

---

Similarly, if there are lot of such dataframes you don't need to write them one by one. Create a string vector using `paste0` and then use `mget` + `bind_rows`.

```
new_df <- bind_rows(mget(paste0('df_', 1:2)), .id = 'id')
```

You can change 2 to whatever number of dataframes that you have in your global environment.